# XSL change the name of first element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How can I use XSL to copy everything after after the first node?

```
<ExternalRequest>
<ApplicationData></ApplicationData>
<ApplicationData></ApplicationData>
<ExternalRequest>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
<ApplicationDataBatch>
<ApplicationData></ApplicationData>
<ApplicationData></ApplicationData>
<ApplicationDataBatch>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your input and output are not valid XML, but assuming you changed the last tag to a closing tag, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ApplicationDataBatch>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </ApplicationDataBatch>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```